# Project.ProjectReferences shows no item instead of list of project dependencies

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using the following code to open solution, load the project and create the compilation.

```
 var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath, new ConsoleProgressReporter());
 Project valueObjectProject = solution.Projects.FirstOrDefault(proj => String.Equals(proj.Name, 
                               "ValueObject", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
 var bofCompilation = await valueObjectProject.GetCompilationAsync();
```

**Issue:** no of items in `valueObjectProject.ProjectReferences` and `compilation.References` is 0, which is not true. The property should show a list of projects on which the `ValueObject` project depends upon. But, I am getting list of all the microsoft assemblies which the project uses under `valueObject.MetadataReferences` and `compilation.ExternalReferences`

Currently, the Diagnostics shows multiple errors of type TypeNotFound because the referenced types are declared in different assemblies. I think this is because the compilation does not have project dependency information. Don't know what is going wrong.

[image]
[image]
[image]

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of MSBuild did you register to load the project and which kind of project is it.  Common causes of issues like this are:

1.) The correct dependencies to build the project are not on the machine (If visual studio can't build the project neither can MSBuildWorkspace)

2.) You are trying to load a .NET Core project with a .NET Framework MSBuild or vica-a-versa

(NOTE: I assume you are following best practices and registering MSBuild via [Microsoft.Build.Locator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Locator/) and not just copying everything to the output directory)

Comment: I am using MSBuild 16. This is .net framework 4.6.2 project and Visual Studio is able to build the project.